# Online Tutorial Not Working, Request for Member not in a structure or Union?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm new to iOS Development, so I've been following a bunch of tutorials online on how to make drill-down applications. I've run into this problem on two builds and I can't seem to get over it. I'm creating a tab bar application. In my app delegate, I define a tab bar, navigation controller, view controller, and an NSDictionary for my .plist. Problem is, when I get to my ViewController.m's file and start telling it to use the navigation controller i created, I get the error "Request for member is something not a structure or union."

I've tried this twice, quadrupled checked the code, and I still don't get it. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Below is the tableView method from my ViewController.m file.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//Get the dictionary of the selected data source.
NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//Get the children of the present item.
NSArray *Children = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Children"];

if([Children count] == 0) {

    DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.indNavControl pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
    [dvController release];
}
else {

    //Prepare to tableview.
    IndustriesViewController *indViewControl = [[IndustriesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"IndustryView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    //Increment the Current View
    indViewControl.CurrentLevel += 1;

    //Set the title;
    indViewControl.CurrentTitle = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];

    //Push the new table view on the stack
    [self.indNavControl pushViewController:indViewControl animated:YES];

    indViewControl.tableDataSource = Children;

    [indViewControl release];
}
```

}

Comment: What line is it failing on? The error message suggests you are trying to access a property using dot notation but that the property is not defined. You seem to be using dot notation a lot in this example so it would help to know where specifically it fails

Comment: The problem is likely in the header file. Possibly an asterisk is missing or not required on one of your properties.

Comment: It fails at [self.indNavControl pushViewController:dvController animated:YES] and [self.indNavControl pushViewControl animated:YES];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you synthesize indNavControl?

Comment: No, because I defined it in my app delegate and it isn't defined int he view controller. I have the file set to import though.

Comment: but you are accessing it via self.indNavControl, would it need to be a member?

Comment: Not necessarily. THe tutorial I used did it the same way but t worked for some reason that I don't understand. Do you have an alternate suggestion? Thanks :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure, if you use self. that's the synythesized setter. If indNavControl is in your app-delegate, you would have to get that via [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] and access it from here

Comment: I'm only somewhat familiar with how to do that. I had to do it for my viewDidLoad method to get a hold of a property list, but I don't know how to translate it. Here's what I have for that:

A37dgAppDelegate *AppDelegate = (A37dgAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  self.tableDataSource = [AppDelegate.industryData objectForKey:@"Rows"]; 

So in trying to think logically, I'm adding self.indNavControl = [AppDelegate.indNavControl ...] but I don't know what to do with the ... part

Comment: you only need one navigationController, the one in your appdelegate. and you won't have to set a member to that either. Try  something like A37dgAppDelegate *AppDelegate = (A37dgAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; [AppDelegate.indNavControll push...];

Comment: Forgive my stupidity, but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do after push. I'm reading up on UIApplication in the iOS resources, but I'm still not able to figure it out. Thanks for sticking with me.

Comment: I'm off for now, contact me tomorrow if you like and send me you project, than I'll look it over. Cheers 8)

Comment: Hey, if possible I'd like to send you my project, but your profile doens't have an email address listed